# SQL Query not giving accurate answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table like this :

```
AID AName GID  GName PID PName   A  B

13  Ant  15     G15  13  904/M3  5  5
13  Ant  15     G15  16  905/M4  4  5
13  Ant  13     New  13  904/M3  6  2
13  Ant  13     New  16  905/M4  1  1
1   AUD  1      G1   13  904/M3  2  4
1   AUD  1      G1   16  905/M4  3  4
1   AUD  2      G2   13  904/M3  4  1
1   AUD  2      G2   16  905/M4  5  2
1   AUD  4      G4   13  904/M3  0  4
1   AUD  4      G4   16  905/M4  1  1
1   AUD  16     TGp  13  904/M3  2  5
1   AUD  16     TGp  16  905/M4  0  1
```

I am trying to write a store procedure which will help me to give a result like this :

```
AName  P1A  P1B  P2A  P2B Total

 G15   5     5   4    5    19
 New   6     2   1    1    10
Ant    11    7   5    6    29   (Total values of G15 and New)
 G1    2     4   3    4    13
 G2    4     1   5    2    12
 G4    0     4   1    1    6
 TGP   2     5   0    1    8
```

AUD    10    14  9    8    41   (Total values of G1, g2, G4 and TGP)

The values in column A, B represents P1A and P1B. Then P2A and P2B represents col. A and B values from other row with same AName. Ant and AUD gives the total only.

I am learning pivot and trying if i can figure out something, but can anyone help me out ?

I tried this SQL but it is not working, I am a newbie here

```
select AName, P1A, P1B, P2A, P2B
from
(
  select AID,AName,GID,GName,PID,PName,A,B
) as sourceTable
Pivot
(
  sum(A), sum(B) for AName in P1A, P1B, P2A, P2B
)
as PivotTable
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added the query. But I dont know what i should do.

Comment: @NoDisplayName Query Added

Comment: @Aramillo sql server. Edited

Comment: Is that a Working code???

Comment: @NoDisplayName No. I am unable to think only how my procedure would be. I feel it is v complicated. Can you please help me out.

Comment: Still am tryigng to understand your Expected output but coudn't. How `P1A`, `P1B`,`P2A`,`P2B` is calculated.

Comment: @NoDisplayName The values in column A, B represents P1A and P1B. Then P2A and P2B represents col. A and B values from other row with  same AName. Ant and AUD gives the total only.